# How to have a service account per bigtable instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am a beginner on Google Cloud and Bigtable, I was wondering if it was possible to setup a **service account** having admin access to a *single bigtable instance* ?

If possible I would like to do it from the console.
This is what I use today:

[image]

Comment: [Instance-level IAM for Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/access-control#granting_instance-level_iam_roles) is now available. I also updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Cloud Bigtable IAM roles, please enable the [Cloud Bigtable API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/bigtable/overview) via the Cloud Console, which you can find by [searching the API Library for "Bigtable"](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?q=bigtable).

Once you've done this, the Cloud Bigtable IAM roles will show up, and you will be able to grant [Cloud Bigtable IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/access-control) to service accounts, as you have done in the screenshot for other services.

That said, please note that all of these roles, including the ones in your screenshot, are not instance-specific, they are service-specific, but affect all instances of that service across the entire project.

To assign IAM roles on a per Cloud Bigtable instance level, follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/access-control#granting_instance-level_iam_roles):

> 1. Go to the [Cloud Bigtable instances page in the GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigtable/instances).
> 2. Check the boxes next to the instances whose roles you want to manage. An information panel appears.
> 3. In the information panel, click **Permissions**.
> 4. Under **Add members**, start typing the email address of the user or service account you want to add, then click the email address of
>      the user or service account.
> 5. Click the **Select a role** drop-down list, then click **Cloud Bigtable** to select a predefined role or **Custom** to select a
>      custom role.
> 6. Click the name of each role that you want to assign.
> 7. Click **Add**. The user or service account is granted the roles that you specified at the instance level.

Answer (score 0):

Instance level permissions are now available and you can assign roles to individual instances. This functionality is accessible via the cloud console by clicking the check box next the Bigtable instance that you would like to configure.